# What version of python is need to install emscripten?

Tags: python, python-3.x, emscripten

In emscripten docs,

> You need Python 2.7.12 or newer because older versions may not work due to a GitHub change with SSL).

Python 3 has supported?

Comment: All the circleci tests seem to use python3, so I'd say yes. https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/.circleci/config.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is supported:

https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/pull/5967

> This PR:
>
> 1. introduces `EMSCRIPTEN_ALLOW_NEWER_PYTHON` to allow Python 3